# how to show another image on hover image in wordpress gallery

Tags: wordpress

how to show  another image on hover image in gallery in wordpress  https://www.castlery.com/lighting/pendant-light.html

Answer (score 1):

You can crate custom post type name gallery in gallery post type you can add field name `title`, `imagefield1` and `imagefield2`. If needed other fields as required then you can retrieve all images from database as particular post then you can get all posts with two images on view mode, another on hover mode show,(to do that you can use jquery). To get all post of particular post type you an refer wordpress.org or request on comment below